# Error: can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field is thrown in the framework

Tags: java, testng, appium

I am using a page factory for my appium framework. The problem is arising when I am trying to run `testng5.xml` where I want to run 2 classes one after another.

I get an error like "**can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field** ".

I get this error at my constructor level.

```
public Homepage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
}
```

Not sure what the issue is in `testng5.xml`. First, the class runs all fine, but problems occur when the 2nd class initiates.

`testng5.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression Suit2">
    <test name="Sanity Tests">
        <parameter name="device" value="Nexus4" />
        <parameter name="port" value="4723" />
        <classes>
            <class name="au.com.intelematics.mobileautomation.settings.SettingsPageTest" />
            <class name="au.com.intelematics.mobileautomation.destinationdownload.DestinationDownloadPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: How and where are you declaring driver?  In your Homepage method, you're only defining it as "WebDriver" yet you're using the AppiumFieldDecorator?  What does the parent class instantiation do?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all, I got this issue resolved by putting proper life cycle for each test.
Earlier I was initializing the driver (ios or android)under `@BeforeClass`. I changed that to `@BeforeMethod` and mentioned `@AfterMethod` for logout action(wherever required) and `driver.quit();` Now the the driver is setup before start of each test method.
Also casted my `WebDriver` to `AppiumDriver` for driver initialization.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is generated when you pass null value in PageFactory. For example

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver=null;
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
// this will throw **can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field**
```

The solution is to pass not null value of in AppiumFieldDecorator.

> Make sure your driver is not null while calling PageFactory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pure `WebDriver`, try using `AppiumDriver <MobileElement>`. Or more specific, if you are working on Android device, then use `AndroidDriver <MobileElement>` or if on IOS device then use `IOSDriver <MobileElement>`. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Suban's answer;

When I changed the driver public to protected static, it is fixed.

```
protected static AppiumDriver driver;
```